# Data synchronisation with server not working anymore

Tags: android, caching, server, google-cloud-firestore

Everything was fine with my app. It loads all the data from the firestore server like usual.

But since a few days, all my data come from the cache. The emulator or my real device can't reach the online database.

My application in firebase still exist and the quota is fine.

I didn't change anything on my app. I know it's still in beta but ...

How can i found the issue and fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research, i found the cause.

My request needed an index to be created in firestore.

No trace in logCat, i'm a bit disappointed but it's works now.